# 1970s short story about a man 'murdered' by his 'home theater' system?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This story features a detective showing up at a dead man's house to investigate his death. The man died from exposure, he was watching a documentary about arctic wolves, and as the house projected the images on the walls it also lowered the temperature to sub-freezing to make the experience truly immersive, killing him in the process.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 1):

As per [Short story where a killer house lowers the temperature to match that of a movie scene the owner is watching](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225822/short-story-where-a-killer-house-lowers-the-temperature-to-match-that-of-a-movie), if you allow for it being a bit later, and the theme being slightly different, this could be "[House Arrest](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1231137)" by Erik Larson.

> **D'Angelo**: Okay. From what I can tell the dead guy, ah, the victim, turned on his video recorder. We found a tape labeled 123 in the machine. See, Palmerston was a movie freak. He liked old flicks. Like Bogart, Redford, Streep, stuff like that. He liked the scary ones, too. Like 123 - we found out it was this creepy movie with a guy named James Arness, about the scientists in the Arctic who find this monster frozen in the ice. Not bad, either.

....

> **D'Angelo:** That's when things start going wrong, see. The dead—ah, Jeez, the victim, being the kind of guy who likes movies, set the mood-response system on high. So Arthur takes over. At first, hey, no problems. A little breeze, some wind noises. Good stuff. Then Arthur goes bonkers